# Accessing background services when not logged in

Tags: services, database, windows-server-2012-r2, wcf

I have a bit of a boggle.

If my server restarts for some reason - auto update, datacentre issues, any other reason - Can an MSSQL database service still be accessed by remote users despite not having been logged on? (assume the service is set to auto start)

Additionally, could a custom made and installed WCF service also be accessed without any changes, or would that need some sort of modification? (also assume it is set to autostart)

I know that some services are certainly avaliable at the winlogon prompt - remote desktop springs to mind (otherwise id never be able to log on!)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, services *by definition* run independent of any interactive logons ("in the background" so to say). The "Service Manager" in Windows takes care of setting up a token and starting the program under its dedicated account.

Custom services can be created as long as they implement the required APIs:

- [Introduction to Windows Service Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=vs.110).aspx) for .NET 4.6
- For comparison, [PyWin32 module 'servicemanager'](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/servicemanager.html)
- Underlying [RegisterServiceCtrlHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685058(v=vs.85).aspx) Win32 API function

Comment: So as its a service it is still going to be running, where as a server application would cease to run as it requires a logon?